# PHP using echo with google analytics event tracking

Tags: php, events, echo, tracking

i need help with this PHP script that doesn't works for some reason as below

```
<?php
.
.
.
echo "<li><a href='#' onclick='print(); return false; _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'check', 'test1', 'Print01']); '>";
echo "</a></li>";
.
.                                       
.
?>
```

if i remove the google tracking event code onclick print() will work without any problem,
does anybody know where is the problem or may be i miss something ?

Comment: Post the full script, or the relevant code.

Comment: `will work without any problem`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What's the error you're getting ?

Comment: no errors just the onclick print doesn't works instead refreshing the page !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're confusing PHP and Javascript code. The "print()" in the onclick handler is Javascript, and unless you have a Javascript function defined that is named `print`, it'll fail and the link will be loaded. There's also no use in having the analytics call *after* returning false, since it never will run.

Edit: I misred a bit. You're using ' in the code, as well as using ' to delimit the text contained. You'd probably be better off by creating a separate function to handle the click event, or you'll have to escape the single quotes.

```
onclick='print(); return false; _gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'check\', \'test1\', \'Print01\']);'
```

.. but remember that PHP will also have escape codes, and you might have to escape the \ as well. I'd rather move it out to a separate function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleClick()
    {
        print();
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'check', 'test1', 'Print01']);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Allowing 'check', 'test1', 'Print01' to be provided as arguments to handleClick will also make reuse easier.

Comment: Hi fiskfisk, the print() is working fine without google tracking code, i tried also by removing the return false; but no luck !